# If $\pi$ has marginals $\mu = \frac{1}{2} \delta_x + \frac{1}{2} \delta_y$ and $\nu$, must $\pi = \mu \otimes \nu$?

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, dirac-delta, ergodic-theory, product-space

Let $X$ be a topological space equipped with the [Borel $\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set).
Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794299/product-measure-with-a-dirac-delta-marginal/794317#comment9415590_794317) whether a measure $\pi$ on the product space $X \times X$ having marginals $\mu = \delta_x$ and $\nu$ implies that $\pi = \mu \otimes \nu$, which is true, I wondered

> If $\pi$ has marginals $\mu = \frac{1}{2} \delta_x + \frac{1}{2} \delta_y$ for $x \ne y \in X$ and $\nu$, must $\pi = \mu \otimes \nu$?

(The measure $\pi$ on $X \times X$ having marginals $\mu$ and $\nu$ means that $\pi(A \times X) = \mu(A)$ and $\pi(X \times B) = \nu(B)$ for all measurable subsets $A, B \subset X$.)

Let $A, B \subset X$ be measurable.

I have been able to adapt the proof from the question mentioned about for the case that $x, y \in A$ and that $x, y \not\in A$, but I am struggling to show the statement for the case that $x \not\in A$ but $y \in A$ (or the other way around).

**My attempts so far.**
As the Borel-$\sigma$-Algebra is generated by measure rectangles of the form $A \times B \subset X \times X$, it suffices to show that $\mu(A) \nu(B) = \pi(A \times B)$.

If $x \not\in A$ but $y \in A$, then $\mu(A)\nu(B) = \frac{1}{2} \nu(B)$.
We have
\begin{equation*}
        0
        \le \pi\big( (A \setminus \{ y \}) \times B\big)
        \le \pi\big( (A \setminus \{ y \}) \times X\big)
        = \mu(A \setminus \{ y \})
        = 0,
    \end{equation*}
so $\pi\big( (A \setminus \{ y \}) \times B\big) = 0$.
Hence $\pi(\{ y \} \times B) = \pi(A \times B)$.
Analogously, we have
\begin{align*}
        0
        \le \pi\big( \big((X \setminus A) \setminus \{ x \}\big) \times B\big)
        \le \pi\big( \big((X \setminus A) \setminus \{ x \}\big) \times X\big)
        = \mu\big((X \setminus A) \setminus \{ x \}\big)
        = 0,
    \end{align*}
implying $\pi\big( \big((X \setminus A) \setminus \{ x \}\big) \times B\big) = 0$ or, equivalently, $ \pi\big( (X \setminus A) \times B\big) = \pi(\{ x \} \times B)$.
These two equations imply
\begin{equation*}
        \pi(\{ x, y \} \times B)
        = \pi\big( (X \setminus A) \times B) + \pi(A \times B)
        = \pi(X \times B)
        = \nu(B).
    \end{equation*}
Hence it remains to show
\begin{equation*}
        \frac{1}{2} \nu(B)
        = \frac{1}{2}  \pi(\{ x, y \} \times B)
        \overset{!}{=} \pi(\{ y \} \times B),
    \end{equation*}
which we can simplify to
\begin{equation*}
        \pi(\{ x \} \times B)
        \overset{!}{=} \pi(\{ y \} \times B).
    \end{equation*}
We have
\begin{align*}
        1 - \nu(B)
        & = \nu(X \setminus B)
        = \pi\big(X \times (X \setminus B)\big)
        \ge \pi\big(\{ x \} \times (X \setminus B)\big) \\
        & = \pi(\{ x \} \times X) - \pi(\{ x \} \times B)
        = \frac{1}{2} - \pi(\{ x \} \times B),
    \end{align*}
that is $\frac{1}{2} \ge \pi(\{ y \} \times B) - \pi(\{ x \} \times B)$.

Comment: We see from the answer that this is false in general.  There are some theorems about this, but they have hypotheses where $\mu,\nu$ have nothing in common (in some sense I do not remember).

Comment: @GEdgar I'd be very interested in these results if you could find it, does absolutely continuity of the measures (for $X = \mathbb R^d$) perhaps play a role?

Comment: I put in the tag `ergodic-theory`.  Maybe someone who knows this will answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is false. Take $X=\{0,1\}$ (with the discrete topology) and let $\nu=\frac12\delta_0 + \frac12 \delta_1$. Then $\pi=\frac12\delta_{(0,1)} + \frac12\delta_{(1,0)}$ has both marginals equal to $\nu$, but is not equal to $\nu\otimes \nu$.

Comment: This remains true with $X = \mathbb R$ wie the usual topology, right?

Comment: @Ramanujan Right!

Comment: I know this is kind of a new question but do you know if there still is a counterexample if we set $X = \mathbb{R}^d$ and let $\nu$ be absolutely continuous with respect to  the Lebesgue measure?