# If $\pi\in P(X^2\times X^2)$ has marginals $\delta_x\times\delta_y$ and $\delta_x\times\nu$, then $\pi=\delta_x\times\delta_y\times\delta_x\times\nu$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification, marginal-distribution, marginal-probability

> Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ and suppose that the probability measure $\pi\in P(X^2\times X^2)$ has the marginals $\delta_x\times\delta_y$ and $\delta_x\times\nu$, where $x, y \in X$ and $\nu$ is a probability measure on $X$. Can we conclude that $\pi$ is the product of its marginals, that is, $\pi=\delta_x\times\delta_y\times\delta_x\times\nu$?

**Proposition 1 (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794299/product-measure-with-a-dirac-delta-marginal)).** If $\pi \in P(Y \times Y)$ has marginals $\delta_x$ and some probability measure $\mu$, then $\pi = \delta_x \times \mu$.

I tried to mimic the proof of proposition 1 to show the question posed above can be answered affirmatively:

*Proof.*
We want to show that for measurable subsets $A, B, C, D \subset X$, we have
$$
\pi(A \times B \times C \times D)
= \delta_x(A) \nu(B) \delta_x(C) \delta_y(D),
$$
which would yield $\pi=\delta_x\times\delta_y\times\delta_x\times\nu$, since rectangles are a $\cap$-stable generator of the $\sigma$-algebra on $X \times X$.

**Case 1.**
Suppose that $x \not\in A$.
Then
$$
0
\le \pi(A \times B \times C \times D)
\le \pi(A \times B \times X \times X)
= \delta_x(A) \nu(B)
= 0
$$
and thus $\pi(A \times B \times C \times D) = 0 = \delta_x(A) \nu(B)$.

**Case 2**
Suppose $x \in A$, then
$$
\delta_x(A) \nu(B) \delta_x(C) \delta_y(D)
= \nu(B) \delta_x(C) \delta_y(D)
= \nu(B) \pi(X \times X \times C \times D)
\ge \nu(B) \pi(A \times X \times C \times D).
$$
We now want to show $\delta_x(C) \delta_y(D) \le \pi(A \times X \times C \times D)$, but I haven't been able to.

If $x \not\in C$ or $y \not\in D$, then both sides are zero.
If $x \in C$ and $y \in D$, then the left side is 1, so we would have to show $\pi(A \times X \times C \times D) \ge 1$, but I am stuck there.

If we could prove that we would have
$$
\delta_x(A) \nu(B) \delta_x(C) \delta_y(D)
= \nu(B) \delta_x(C) \delta_y(D)
\le \pi(A \times X \times C \times D)
\le \delta_x(A) \nu(B) \delta_x(C) \delta_y(D),
$$
which yields the statement. $\square$

**Can this proof be completed or is the statement even false?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\delta_{\{x\}} \times \delta_{\{y\}} = \delta_{\{ (x, y) \}}$ is Dirac measure on $X^2$, we can use proposition 1 with $Y = X^2$ to conclude that $\pi$ is indeed the product of its marginals.