# $W^1(μ,\frac{δ_{x_0}+δ_{x_1}}{2})=\frac{1}{2}(∫d(x_0,y)μ(dy)+∫d(x_1,y)μ(dy))$?

Tags: probability-theory, optimal-transport

I was looking at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/793852/340973) to try to understand a bit better the [Wasserstein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric). In the thread that $$W^1(μ,δ_{x_0})=∫d(x_0,y)μ(dy).$$ But I was wondering if this remains true for $$W^1(μ,\frac{δ_{x_0}+δ_{x_1}}{2})=\frac{1}{2}(∫d(x_0,y)μ(dy)+∫d(x_1,y)μ(dy)).$$ I know we have the $\le$-inequality because of the triangle inequality but I am not sure if we have the equality.

Comment: $\delta_{x_{0}}+\delta_{x_{1}}$ is not a probability measure.

Comment: Sorry, then say we have $(\delta_{x_0}+\delta_{x_1})/2$

Answer (score 1):

No, usually not. For example, if $\mu=\frac 1 2(\delta_{x_0}+\delta_{x_1})$, then the left side is of course $0$, while the right side is $\frac 1 2 d(x_0,x_1)$.

Comment: Thank you. But still $W^1(\frac{1}{2}(\delta_{x_0}+\delta_{x_1}),\frac{1}{2}(\delta_{y_0}+\delta_{y_1}))=d(x_0,y_0)+d(x_1,y_1)$ or something like that no?

Comment: No. For one, the normalization on the right side is off: If $x_0=x_1$ and $y_0= y_1$, one should get $d(x_0,y_0)$. But also $x_0$ might be closer to $y_1$ and $x_1$ closer to $x_0$, in which case transporting all mass from $x_0$ to $y_1$ and all mass from $x_1$ to $y_0$ is certainly cheaper.